# How to setup automation testing project in visual studio 2017 using C# & How to RUN the Test Scripts in TFS

Tags: automation, automated-tests, azure-devops, visual-studio-2017

Environment is 
1. Visual Studio 2017 
2. Visual Studio Team server

In My requirement is, If i update "TEST SCRIPTS" code in Visual Studio Team server its will build automatically every release. But i need to to **RUN** the updated "TEST SCRIPTS" in Visual Studio Team server.

Comment: Create a task to run your "scripts". If there's a task that already exists for this (e.g. nunit, mstest, etc.) then just use it. If it's something else (e.g. a directory full of perl scripts) then you'll need to create a custom task. Googling found this for me: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483291.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are many tasks to run test, such as Visual Studio Test, Maven Test, Run Functional Test. So you can create a unit test/coded UI test project in VS 2017 and run the test through Visual Studio Test task.

Related article: [Get started with continuous testing](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/continuous-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-continuous-testing).

I recommend you run the test during the build.

Regarding run the test once the Test Script code be changed, you can setup a CI build (Triggers tab). If you want to do test in release, you need to publish artifact (test project build result), and configure release with Continuous Deployment mode (Triggers)